# Android 4.4 WebView issue with requestFocusFromTouch

Tags: android, webview, scroll, android-4.4-kitkat

I am seeing some unexpected behavior when using a WebView in Android 4.4 (build target 18).  One one page in particular we have some edit text fields, and to get the soft keyboard to pop up appropriately, we had to use a code snippet similar to the ones described here:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7189

```
    webview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                        v.requestFocus();
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This worked as expected up through version 4.3, but beginning with 4.4 the code above caused an undesired effect of having the content of the webview snap/scroll back to the top of the page on the completion of a touch - after scrolling down the page.

Has anyone else experienced this new behavior - or figured out a workaround?  The only thing I have come up with so far would be to subclass a webview that allows the edits (so the code above can be removed from read-only pages that now have the scrolling issue).  Of course, if a page both scrolls and has edit fields, this would not work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes I am facing exactly the same issue in some what similar situation. Did you get any fixes?